# C:\ hidden but can still be accessed via a shortcut

Tags: windows, shortcuts, file-permissions

I currently have C: hidden through an Active Directory group policy.

The students have worked out that they can bring a short cut of their C: from home and when they run it they can see and access the whole of `C:\`.

Is there a way that this can be stopped?

Comment: Which group policy settings did you sue to hide it?  Keep in mind that if they can boot from USB and there's no disk encryption, then they can take all of C:.  You may want to reconsider your overall security strategies.

Comment: What is the harm in them accessing it and browsing through it if they cannot write or look in other user directories because of your (hopefully) properly set permissions?